# apache rewrite using a wildcard in the middle

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to write a rewrite that will repoint:
    `www.example.com/thing1/thing2/thing3/thing4/product-name`

to 
    `www.example.com/product-name.html`

I tried:
    `RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^thing1/thing2/thing3/thing4/(.*)$ /$1 [R=302,L]`

but I got a 404.  All help welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these in all try

```
RewriteRule ^thing1/thing2/thing3/thing4/(.*)$ /$1.html [R=302,L]
```

instead of

```
RewriteRule ^thing1/thing2/thing3/thing4/(.*)$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```